# How do I integrate Cloud Spanner with a GAE Python app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-spanner

I would like to create a hello world Python app which calls a simple Google Cloud Spanner table.

I'd like an end-to-end example with population of the DB, querying a couple of tables and possibly inserting an element from App Engine endpoint. [1] provides a good initial guidance but I was hoping for some cut-and-paste code.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

Comment: Also please can an admin add the Cloud-Spanner tag? I can't with <1500rep

Answer (score 2):

If you're using App Engine standard, unfortunately you'll have to use the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/), documented on the page you linked:

> The Cloud Spanner Client Libraries mentioned on this page are supported on Google Compute Engine (GCE), Google App Engine - Flexible Environment, and Google Container Engine (GKE). If you are using Google App Engine - Standard Environment, please access Cloud Spanner using the REST Interface, instead of the client libraries.

If you use App Engine flexible environment you can reference [Getting Started with Python](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/python/).